# Ruby: do not do certain combinations with array elements

Tags: ruby, arrays, combinations, ruby-1.9.3

I have a list of combinations:

```
('a'..'z').to_a.combination(3)
```

but I want to generate a new list with the same starting set `('a'..'z')`:

```
('a'..'z').to_a.combination(5)
```

Is there any way to have ruby use the old set `combination(3)`, in the new set `combination(5)`, so it saves some time on the clock?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if there is or isn't any easy way to re-use the already-generated options, but don't forget that adding two more "positions" [drastically grows the number of combinations (Wolfram Alpha)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=nCr%5b26%2C5%5d%2C+nCr%5b26%2C3%5d) -- there's 25 times more combinations in the `5` case than the `3` case.

The 25 times more processing time for whatever it is you're *doing* with the data is going to dominate, by far, over whatever time Ruby spends in preparing the combinations for you.

Comment: Nodnod, couldn't have said it better.

Answer (score 2):

There is, but I doubt you'll be saving much time, unless you're running on Rubinius or some other non-native implementation. In the reference implementation, `Array#combination` is written in tight C, and I very much doubt that the added processing of appending and looping and differencing that you would need to do in order to reuse those results would be less than what native `combination` uses up.